# How should I protect a static Wordpress file directory from the outside world?

Tags: wordpress

I'm taking over the admin of a WP site that serves static docs from a dedicated directory. The current directory resides on the top level (/public_html/docs) which seems susceptible to snooping. The site sits behind a login firewall.

The file directory contains >500 individual files, so uploading and hand-editing individual links seems absurd. (At least to me.)

Should I move this directory to a more secure location within the WP directory? Or, what is the preferred way to configure .htaccess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a minimum I would disable Directory Listing by using an .htaccess file that sits inside your /public_html/docs directory.

```
IndexIgnore *
```

Possibly a more secure method would be to move the docs directory outside your public_html directory. Then use a PHP script that can serve your document by passing a variable, such as www.site.com/serve_doc.php?name=xxxx.pdf.

Here is some code to accomplish this:

```
// get the file name
$file = $_GET['name'];
$dir = "/home/xxxx/docs/";
$fp = fopen($dir.$file, 'rb');
if(!$fp) { exit; }

// open the file
$finfo = finfo_open();
$filetype = finfo_file($finfo, $file, FILEINFO_MIME);
finfo_close($finfo);
$filename = $file;

// send the right headers
header("Cache-Control: ");// leave blank to avoid IE errors
header("Pragma: ");// leave blank to avoid IE errors
header("Content-Type: " .$filetype );
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($dir.$file));

// dump the file and stop the script
fpassthru($fp);
exit();
```

Of course you'll want to add some authentication to validate whether the user should be able to call this PHP script. One possible way would be to call the Wordpress function `is_user_logged_in` in that script before serving the file.

Comment: Thanks @trevor, I'll have to use the minimal approach due to lack of developer expertise.